# How is it possible to create highly customised repeated local notification in iOS using UNCalendarNotificationTrigger + UNUserNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

Currently, I am using `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` + `UNUserNotificationCenter` to create highly customised repeated local notification for a reminder app.

I am able to create local notification with the very basic repetitive rule.

### Repeat yearly

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

//
// Repeat every year on 5th Oct, 3:00 AM
//
dateComponents.month = 10
dateComponents.day = 5

dateComponents.hour = 3
dateComponents.minute = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
    dateMatching: dateComponents,
    repeats: true
)
```

### Repeat monthly

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

//
// Repeat every 5th of month, 3:00 AM
//
dateComponents.day = 5

dateComponents.hour = 3
dateComponents.minute = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
    dateMatching: dateComponents,
    repeats: true
)
```

### Repeat weekly

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

//
// Repeat every Monday, 3:00 AM
//
dateComponents.weekday = 2

dateComponents.hour = 3
dateComponents.minute = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
    dateMatching: dateComponents,
    repeats: true
)
```

### Repeat daily

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

//
// Repeat everyday, 3:00 AM
//
dateComponents.hour = 3
dateComponents.minute = 0

let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
    dateMatching: dateComponents,
    repeats: true
)
```

---

But, what if I want to create repetitive notification with more complex rules?

- Repeat every 2 days
- Repeat daily until 25th December 2025
- Repeat weekly on Monday, Tuesday and Friday
- Repeat every 2 weeks on Monday, Tuesday and Friday until 25th December 2025

### Reminder feature in Google Keep

First, I thought it isn't possible. But, for some well known apps like Google Keep, it is able to provide such feature to users.

I have tested their reminders, I can confirm Google Keep is using local notification and not remote push notification.

I still can receive notification even I am on Air Plane mode.

[image]

---

***Does anyone have idea, how I can create highly customized repeated local notification in iOS, which enables me to specific***

- Repetitive internal (Repeat every N days)
- End date of the repetitive reminder (Repeat daily until X)
- Repeat on which day (Repeat weekly on Monday, Tuesday and Friday)
- Combination of all the above

---

### Side Note

In Android, I am able to implement such feature. Reason is that, `AlarmManager` in Android allows developer to execute our custom app code, when date + time for the reminder hit. This enables us to implement with the following strategy

1. Queue the next non-repeated alarm by specific date + time.
2. When the alarm occurs, compute what is the nearest date + time based on the complex repetitive rule. Repeat step 1 with newly computed date + time.

---

### Basic code snippet to create local notification in iOS

For reference purpose, the following is the basic code snippet I use to create local notification in iOS.

```
import UIKit

struct LocalDate {
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    let day: Int
}

struct LocalTime {
    let hour: Int
    let minute: Int
}

extension Date {
    var localDate: LocalDate {
        let current = Calendar.current
        let components = current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: self)
        let year = components.year!
        let month = components.month!
        let day = components.day!
        return LocalDate(year: year, month: month, day: day)
    }
    
    var localTime: LocalTime {
        let current = Calendar.current
        let components = current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: self)
        let hour = components.hour!
        let minute = components.minute!
        return LocalTime(hour: hour, minute: minute)
    }
    
    func adding(_ component: Calendar.Component, _ value: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: component, value: value, to: self)!
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.badge, .sound, .alert]

        center.requestAuthorization(options: options) { (flag, error) in
            if flag == true {
                
                // Registering user notification
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    
                    self.performNotificationSetup(uuidString: "1")
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "(Provide reason why we need Notifications permission)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in

                        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                            return
                        }

                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                                print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    alert.addAction(settingsAction)
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                    
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }

        }
        
    }
    
    private func performNotificationSetup(uuidString: String) {

        // Compute local date and local time for the next minute.
        let date = Date()
        let nextMinuteDate = date.adding(.minute, 1)
        let nextMinuteLocalDate = nextMinuteDate.localDate
        let nextMinuteLocalTime = nextMinuteDate.localTime
        
        //
        // STEP 1 : Create the Notification's Content
        //
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "\(uuidString) My App"
        content.body = "Body \(nextMinuteDate.localTime)"
        
        print("\(content.title)")
        print("\(content.body)")
        
        //
        // STEP 2 : Specify the Conditions for Delivery
        //
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

        dateComponents.year = nextMinuteLocalDate.year
        dateComponents.month = nextMinuteLocalDate.month
        dateComponents.day = nextMinuteLocalDate.day

        dateComponents.hour = nextMinuteLocalTime.hour
        dateComponents.minute = nextMinuteLocalTime.minute
        
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
                 dateMatching: dateComponents,
                 repeats: false
        )
        
        //
        // STEP 3 : Create and Register a Notification Request
        //
        // Create the request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString,
                    content: content, trigger: trigger)

        // Schedule the request with the system.
        let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
           if error != nil {
               // Handle any errors.
               print("error \(error)")
           }
        }
        
        print("ok")
    }
}
```

---

### My raw guess on how this is implemented by Google Keep

1. Whenever user launches the Google Keep app, the app will compute the nearest upcoming reminder activation time, for every notes.
2. Then, the app the sort all the reminder activation times, and pick the most recent 64 reminder activation times.
3. Cancel the entire notification queue, and then re-queue the most recent 64 reminder activation times, as non-repeat notification.

Of course, this is based on assumption, user will at least launch the app again, before all the 64 notifications finish execution.

Comment: Have you consider using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` for some of this notifications? For example, every two days, it won't be as accurate as working with dates but is probably good enough.

Comment: But, I can't visualize how `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` able to solve the entire problem.

Comment: The short answer is "no". You need to schedule a series of individual notifications and each time your app is opened check and schedule more notifications. This does mean that if the user doesn't open your app periodically then notifications will stop.  Feel free to submit an enhancement request to Apple as I agree there could be more power added to their scheduling api.

Comment: On the surface, it seems not possible to implement such feature. But, Google Keep somehow about to achieve such. Do you have a good guess on how it is implemented? My guess is, whenever user opens the app, Google Keep will perform computation on what is the nearest upcoming reminder activation time for every note. Then, it will pick the nearest 64 reminder time, and schedule them as non-repeat. Of course, this takes assumption that user will re-open the app, before all the 64 reminders happen.